# COM+, transactions and ContextUtil.SetAbort()

Tags: c#, com+

I got a serviced component which looks something like this (not written by me):

```
[Transaction(TransactionOption.Required, Isolation = TransactionIsolationLevel.Serializable, Timeout = 120), EventTrackingEnabled(true)]
public class SomeComponent : ServicedComponent
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            //some db operation
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            ContextUtil.SetAbort();
            throw;
        }
}
```

Is the `ContextUtil.SetAbort()` really required? Won't the exception abort the transaction when the component is left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you want to manage the transaction manually.

Your component will vote automatically to abort (in case any exception is raised), or commit, if you decorate your operation with the `[AutoComplete]` attribute  in this way:

```
[AutoComplete]
public void DoSomething()
```

**EDIT:**

For more info about this attribute, see [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.autocompleteattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The transaction automatically calls SetComplete if the method call
>   returns normally. If the method call throws an exception, the
>   transaction is aborted.

Anyway if you are (in the rare case) that really need to manage the transaction manually, is really important that you don't leave your transactions in doubt. I'm missing in your code the `ContextUtil.SetComplete();` that should be explicitly called.

Comment: what happends if ContextUtil is not used att all and no components is tagged with `AutoComplete`?

Comment: That's actually a very good question. In such scenario, where no transaction management is to be performed (you don't set either manually or automatically the [consistent bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.contextutil.mytransactionvote(v=vs.110).aspx) to true), if you instantiate the serviced-component, invoke the operation, and after that you dispose it, the transaction will be committed. *But*, if you execute the same operation, without disposing the component... the transaction will be timed-out after 60 secs. (default time-out), and will be aborted.

Comment: And following the same scenario, if from within your operation, an exception is thrown, it won't be taken into account for voting the transaction to abort, it will be committed (!) if you dispose the object immediately after the call. Again, if you don't dispose it and let the object instance keep activated, the transaction will be aborted,  but not because and exception was thrown inside your logic, just because the transaction is timed-out.